# Can't use PeanoNat.Nat.add_assoc in proof

Tags: coq

```
Require Import PeanoNat.

Check PeanoNat.Nat.add_assoc.
```

Output:

```
Nat.add_assoc
     : forall n m p : nat, n + (m + p) = n + m + p
```

So, the theorem is defined.

But when I create a theorem and try to use it, it gives an error:

```
Theorem a : forall a b c d e f,
    a + b + c + d + e = f.
Proof.
  intros.
  PeanoNat.Nat.add_assoc a (b + c) d.
```

> Error: The reference PeanoNat.Nat.add_assoc was not found in the
>   current environment.

Why can't it find the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes after `Proof.` is not the proof itself. It's a series of instructions, called tactics, that tells Coq how to build a proof. `add_assoc` is a proof, not a tactic that builds a proof. You would use the tactic `rewrite (Nat.add_assoc a (b + c) d)` to rewrite (any part of) the goal according to the equality

```
Nat.add_assoc a (b + c) d
  : a + (b + c + d) = a + (b + c) + d
```

However, your goal `a + b + c + d + e = f` does not contain either of those terms—`+` is left associative and your goal is actually `(((a + b) + c) + d) + e = f`—so this tactic will fail. In fact, your goal is unprovable, but I assume that it's just for example.  You may also be interested in the tactic `apply [prf]`. It takes the conclusion (thing on the right side of all the `->`s and `forall`s) of `prf`, matches it against the goal, and gives you subgoals for all of its hypotheses. See also: [the Coq tactic reference](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html).

Comment: These square brackets around `prf` in `apply prf` are just for your explanation, right? They should not be there in normal Coq code? I thought that it was a variant of `apply` that I didn't know, but now I think I just misunderstood your post.

Comment: "your goal is unprovable, but I assume that it's just for example" - yes

Comment: @eponier Yes, the brackets are just to show that it's an argument that can change. Actual usage does not have them.